# Populate php array from mysql with different values for the same array index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, populate

I have a mysql DB with those column id , idUser , idCompany , idProfession for users table.

Now i would Select all those field and make an array that is build in this way : 
array[idUser] = array [id=> x , idCompany => xx , idProfession => xxx)

For example 1 user could work for more company and do different profession. 
So each array[idUser] Could have multiple array(id, idCompany,idProfession)  and i would have 1 result for each idUser instead multiple result for the same idUser.

Now after i did the query i wrote this code but of course id doesnt do what i want becouse it replace always the same element with another one cause the while loop.

```
$data=array();
$sql_result="SELECT etc...........";

    while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result,MYSQL_BOTH)){
        $data[idUser] = array('idCompany' => $rows['idCompany'], 'profession' => $rows['idProfession'] );
```

I was thinking to do a for loop in the while , store the data in a tmp array.

But i had to stop becouse i didnt understand how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
$users=array();
$sql_result="SELECT * FROM users";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result,MYSQL_BOTH)){
    $users[ $row['idUser'] ][] = array('idCompany' => $row['idCompany'], 'profession' => $row['idProfession'] ); 
}
```

This will populate the array like this:

```
array(
  idUser => array(
      array('idCompany', 'profession'),
      array('idCompany', 'profession'),
      etc..
     )
)
```

Comment: No problem Jasper, happends to us all my friend!